# Trying to draw a simple plot in django using pandas plot :AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'to_html'

Tags: django, pandas, matplotlib

Hi I am trying to draw a simple plot in *django*. However on passing the data frame I get an

> AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'to_html'.

Please assist for I am new to django. Thanks.

My code is as below:

## Create your views here.

```
def index(request):

    persons=Adult.objects.all()[:5]
    personsdf=persons.to_dataframe(fieldnames=['Age','nativecountry'])
    personsdf['Age']=pd.to_numeric(personsdf['Age'])
    personsdf=personsdf.groupby('nativecountry')['Age'].mean().plot(kind='bar')
    context=personsdf.to_html()

    return HttpResponse(context)
```

Comment: you cannot call .to_html() on the plot.

Comment: what can I call on the plot?

Comment: try to call plt.show() instead of context=personsdf.to_html(), calling plt.show() displays a figure